# Cor Producing Different Results than LM

Tags: r, linear-regression, correlation

In rstudio, I used the cor function and got this result between Margin and TOTAL_EMPLOYEES: -0.1033

However, I'm trying to produce a scatterplot and line of best fit for a visual representation. I'd rather not use pairs (because there's a lot of dependent variables that I ran cor with; I'd rather just select the key findings to present). I attempted this code:

```
plot(df_full$TOTAL_EMPLOYEES, df_full$Margin, xlab="TOTAL_EMPLOYEES", ylab="Margin4 ", pch=19)
abline(lm(df_full$Margin~df_full$TOTAL_REVENUE), col="red") # regression line (y~x)
```

To confirm the line of best fit, I ran this:

```
lm(formula = df_full$Group_4 ~ df_full$TOTAL_EMPLOYEES)
```

But that produced:

```
Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  df_full$TOTAL_EMPLOYEES  
          3.004e+00               -1.456e-05
```

Should I not have expected the slope to be -0.1033?

Comment: Why should it? `cor(x, y)^2` should be equal to `summary(fit)$r.squared`. I am assuming `fit <- lm(y ~ x)`.

Comment: I chalk this up to my lack of statistics background. Am I to understand that I cannot use the value produced by cor (0.1033) to say "There is a very, very minor correlation between these two variables?"

Comment: Hi, me again, I re-read cor in R, and I believe I can. Please educate me on what the value -1.456e-05 would mean for me in this case?

Comment: OK, 1) *"There is a very, very minor correlation between these two variables"* yes, you are right. Note also that the Pearson correlation estimator is `r`, and `r.squared`, the coefficient of determination is, well, its square. 2) The value `-1.456e-05` is the slope of the regression line. Such a small value means the line is nearly horizontal and you should interpret this, combined with an `r.squared == (-0.1033)^2`, that the variable `TOTAL_EMPLOYEES` does **not** explain `Group_4`.

Comment: Thanks, Rui. What's interesting to me is that the abline on the plot is not nearly horizontal... I suspect I'm doing something wrong on that front. Any thoughts?

Comment: If I plot `abline` with those coefficients, it's indistinguishable from an horizontal line. `ab <- c(3.004e+00, -1.456e-05); plot(3); abline(ab)`.